# Microsoft Azure realtime charts for externals

Tags: azure, charts, real-time, powerbi

since a couple of weeks I'm working with Microsoft Azure and I wonder if there is a possibility to create realtime charts in my Web App for external customers. 
I know Microsoft provides two different services called 'Power BI', which supports realtime charts and 'Power BI embedded'. But my problem is that, as far as I know, Power BI is only intended for internal users and Power BI embedded, which is inteded for charts e.g. in Web Apps for external customers, only provides reports which are not realtime. 
Am I missing something or is it currently not possible to provide realtime charts inside web apps with the given services of Azure? If yes, what would be alternatives to achieve my goal?

Thank you very much in advance.

Kind regards,
Felix

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Power BI Embedded, with the data source using a Direct Query connection to Azure SQL Database or Azure SQL Datawarehouse.  Every user action in the report (filtering, drilling etc) will generate a query against the database.

That Power BI Embedded architecture is explained on this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/power-bi-embedded-what-is-power-bi-embedded

Direct Query is explained on this page:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-azure-sql-database-with-direct-connect/

Comment: It seems people are being urged to migrate to power bi premium and the old embedded way will be discontinued. https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/19255045-power-bi-premium-needs-lower-pricing-tiers 
I think this makes this question even more relevant as the 600+ dollars a month seems high for entry level projects.

Answer (score 0):

1) Consider that Real Time is like in an IOT scenario where you see your graphics on your dashboard moving in Real Time and not after a refresh. So in this context you should consider using `Azure Stream Analytics Jobs`. It's get an input from a blob storage, an event Hub, ..., and then in output you can use your `power BI` account to write in real time events ingested from Azure Streaming Analytics. Very powerfull! you use SQL for querying the input, the only thing to be aware is the thumbling time window that is somehow new to the SQL language.

2) Letting your customer access to the dashboard I would suggest you to pubblicate your dashboard for free access, and then secure your dashboard inside a web app on which you can apply a security pattern. You can also invite people outside of your organisation via email. Which is faster than the previous solution, but people accessing to your report must have a power BI Pro license. You can use the free trial for 60 days.

Hope that helps!
Cheers!